# pytorch - gradients not calculated for parameters

Tags: pytorch

```
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float, device=device))
b = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float, device=device))
c = a + 1
d = torch.nn.Parameter(c, requires_grad=True,)
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    yhat = d + b * x_train_tensor
    error = y_train_tensor - yhat
    loss = (error ** 2).mean()
    loss.backward()
    print(a.grad)
    print(b.grad)
    print(c.grad)
    print(d.grad)
```

Prints out

```
None
tensor([-0.8707])
None
tensor([-1.1125])
```

How do I learn the gradient for a and c? variable d needs to stay a parameter

Comment: Here, c is a regular tensor, not a parameter, so PyTorch does not compute gradients of them. This tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MswxJw-8PvE) may help you.

Comment: @WasiAhmad what about a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, when you create a new tensor, like `torch.nn.Parameter()` or `torch.tensor()`, you are creating a **leaf node** tensor.

And when you do something like `c=a+1`, `c` will be **intermediate node**. You can `print(c.is_leaf)` to check whether the tensor is leaf node or not. Pytorch will not calculate the gradient of intermediate node in default.

In your code snippet, `a`, `b`, `d` are all leaf node tensor, and `c` is intermediate node. `c.grad` will `None` as pytorch doesn't calculate the gradient for intermediate node. `a` is isolated from the graph when you call `loss.backword()`. That's why `a.grad` is also `None`.

If you change the code to this

```py
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float, device=device))
b = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float, device=device))
c = a + 1
d = c
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    yhat = d + b * x_train_tensor
    error = y_train_tensor - yhat
    loss = (error ** 2).mean()
    loss.backward()
    print(a.grad) # Not None
    print(b.grad) # Not None
    print(c.grad) # None
    print(d.grad) # None
```

You will find `a` and `b` have gradients, but `c.grad` and `d.grad` are None, because they're intermediate node.

Comment: Is there a way for d to stay a parameter but as an intermediate node?

Comment: @algogator I think older version of pytorch can set .reqiure_grad to true for intermediate node, but the latest version seems not allowed to do that.